# Cant add new SceneKit Scene File to art.scnassets

Tags: scenekit, arkit, xcode9-beta

Currently using Xcode 9 beta 6 and can't seem to find any way to get a Scenekit Scene File placed into the art.scnassets folder.

If I add a new files from the art.scnassets folder the file never gets created.

If I add a new file from the target folder then try and drag it into the art.scnassets folder, it automatically makes a copy. I then attempt to deleter the original however it deletes both the original and the copy.

How can I go about creating a "Scenekit Scene File" and have it placed into the art.scnassets folder in Xcode 9 beta 6.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you tried to move the file via the finder?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on art.scnassets and select 'open in finder', manually copy the items there. Worked for me.